# IIS 7 email forwarding

Tags: email, iis-7, forwarding

We have set up an IIS7 box in our company as a hosting server.
Some clients want their email addressed with their domain name forwarded to their respected email addresses (like, johndoe@domain.com -> forward -> bob@yahoo.com).

How can this be accomplished? it should be for several domains on the server and the mails should be forwarded to various other domains and email providers.

Thanks,
roman

Comment: Which email server are you using? You specify IIS but it's quite likely that you're using somethign else for your email. If you are using the IIS SMTP server, please explicitly specify this.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a windows hosting platform you need to follow the SPLA guidleines on how a hosted IIS or EMAIl service should be set up.  You should have gotten access to that documentation when you signed up for the SPLA license. (it's behind the partner protal or I'd provide the link) SPLA is the ONLY way you can license microsoft products for a hosted environment, luckily it's actually less expensive than buying the actual products.  See [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/serviceproviders/licensing/default.mspx) for more details